# How to Set a Range outside a Loop and use it inside

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

Î've read lots of questions recommanding me to avoid using Select. So I've tried to set a target cell but I've met a problem:

I want to use a For Loop to fill a table, but the target cell will change each time with the Loop going on. For example:

```
Sub try()

Dim target As Range
Set target = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1)

For i = 1 To 10
    target.Value = i
Next i

End Sub
```

So can I use a Range in Loop or not?

If I set the target in the `For Loop`, I'm afraid it will not be faster than I choose directly the cell `Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1)`in the Loop? Because I'll actually have lots of targets to use, so I wish to find a easier method to set the targets and fill them everytime without setting them one by one.

Sorry if I've post a duplicate question because I didn't find a similar question or an answer on the net. If you've got an idea, please leave a comment. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value = i` directly instead of setting target to a cell.

Comment: Because I have lots of targets to use, for example : `Worksheets("Data").Cells(i,1).Value = i`, and `Worksheets("Data").Cells(i,2).Value = i +1`, and I want also to get some informations during the `Loop`, like `Colour = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i,10).Text`

Comment: So in your opinion, it's not a good idea to set a `Range` before and use them during the Loop?

Comment: `Set target = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1)` this line will give you error unless you declare and initialize variable `i`

Comment: If you are using large range then using `Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value = i` instead of `Set target = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1)   target.Value = i` will be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, I think it's not possible to do so. It's just a little chaos in the Loop, because I've lots of `Worksheets` and `Cells` inside.

Comment: I've think about that, but does it works faster than I just use directly `Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value = i` ? It seems more evident?

Comment: For a large range, yes it will be faster.

Comment: You can use `For Each` instead of indexed `For`. But if you would give us a bit more details about what you want to do we could give you more advice.

Comment: @Rémi Thank you, and I've used `For Each` in stead of `For`. My object is actually to fill a report. So I have to "Read" each line, like "Colour", "Type" etc, then fill this report with another sheet, which contains the results like "Colour : Red", "Type : A1". So I need to set lots of things and check if it's the correct answer that I need.

Comment: Get the values from the entire range to 2d array via `.Value` property, process that array, it much more faster then accessing each cell individually. Also you can create one more 2d array for output, and assign values from array to cells in one turn.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about "reading" each line.  This code uses a `For Each` and examines each cell to see what to do.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim rMyRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    'Define a range on the same sheet.
    Set rMyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A15,C1:C20,D18,E19:E20")

    'Add another range using Union just for the hell of it.
    Set rMyRange = Union(rMyRange, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F30"))

    'Step through each cell in rMyRange and decide what to do based on contents/formatting of cell.
    For Each rCell In rMyRange
        If rCell = "Colour" Then 'Value is default property.
            rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            Select Case rCell.Font.Color
                Case 255  'Red
                    rCell = "Red"
                Case 5287936 'Green
                    rCell = "Green"
                Case Else
                    rCell = "Some Other Colour"
            End Select
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not so useful for my work. I think it's me that didn't well explained my needs. I want to fill a table (a report of quality control of a product). For example, TV 1 | Colour | Size | Price, and TV2 | Colour | Size | Price. And for each cell in the report, I need to find the result in another sheet, and check if this is the result of that 'TV' I need to fill (this is the result of TV1 or TV2). Then check if this is the answer of colour, or the answer of size, price,etc. At last, fill the report by the correct answer.

Comment: Ah right, so you have text on both sheets to perform the match - e.g. on Sheet1 you have a cell with "TV1" written in it and you want to look up "TV1" on another sheet and return the corresponding colour, size, price, etc which are in the adjacent columns?

Comment: Yes exactly! And so I want to do a several `Set` outside the Loop (if it's possible) and use the `Colour.value = NewReport.Colour.Value`, something like this. I think that could be faster and easier for reading and maintaining.